# Loading data from local json file to create google maps marker in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using JS Google maps API to create a custom map, to insert Marker I need to load coordinates from a local JSON file using pure javascript, I'm not an JS expert, normally I used Jquery.
I followed this [guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/importing_data?hl=it#maps_earthquake_markers-javascript) but it's not working, it give me an error related to the Json file:

Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'

Here's my code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
   
    let map;

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.4636707, 9.1881263),
            mapTypeId: "terrain",
        });

        // Create a <script> tag and set the USGS URL as the source.
        const script = document.createElement("script");

        // This example uses a local copy of the GeoJSON stored at
        // http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_week.geojsonp
        script.src =
            "test.json";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    }

    // Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
    // set of coordinates.
    const eqfeed_callback = function (results) {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
            const lat = results.features[i].Latitudine;
            const lng = results.features[i].Longitudine;
            const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);

            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
            });
        }
    };

    window.initMap = initMap;
    window.eqfeed_callback = eqfeed_callback;
   
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap&v=weekly"defer></script>
```

And here's my JSON file:

```
{
"features" :[
    {
        "Latitudine":"45.47084",
        "Longitudine":"9.21033"
    },
    {
        "Latitudine":"45.4798289",
        "Longitudine":"9.2040963"
    },
    {
        "Latitudine":"45.48455",
        "Longitudine":"9.21542"
    },
    {
        "Latitudine":"45.4790683",
        "Longitudine":"9.2097079"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: That guide is about **JSONP**, not JSON.

Comment: I don't know the difference, so How can I get this with a json file in pure JS?

Comment: Maybe look some some of the answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: I achieved it by using Jquery